# What is the _UID used for in Cappuccino?

Tags: cappuccino, uid

Cappuccino defines a _UID property for every instance of objects it creates, but is this used for anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used in dozens of places, which you could see by doing something like "git grep UID" on the source code. Most often it is used as a hash key. Also, it's spelled "Cappuccino."